# International phone no pattern in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have to use this pattern in textfield 92 123 0123456789 .Made a text field to take phone number in it. In attribute inspector i have done keyboard type to Number pad and in text i give pattern to take numbers from `0123456789` .  When i run an app and enter any value first it takes alphabets also and my pattern is also not working. How we can do that it only take value in digits and value pattern should only go with this pattern `923330123456789` , as it should not take + or 00 before 92 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement `textField delegate` something like,

```
 -(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{


// allow back space
if (string.length == 0) {

    return YES;
}

NSCharacterSet *set = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"] invertedSet];

if (([string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:set].location != NSNotFound) ) {

    return NO;

}

if (range.location == 0 && ![string  isEqual: @"9"]) {
    return NO;
}
if (range.location == 1 && ![string  isEqual: @"2"]) {
    return NO;

}


return YES;
}
```

and don't forget to set

```
  yourTextField.delegate = self;
```

in your `viewDidload`.

**Update :**

You can show alert something like,

```
  if (range.location == 0 && ![string  isEqual: @"9"]) {




    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"First character must be 9" message:@"" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show]; // It's for demo. `UIAlertView` is deprecated , you can use `UIAlertController` instead

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: let me try? @Lion

Comment: it will take first character as `9` only and second as `2` only! let me know if requirement is another!

Comment: This is working perfect . Can we make an error message or toast if user ry to insert wrong pattern in ur code? @Lion

Comment: yes ! you can show alert or toast before returning `no` !

Comment: under which returning no . @Lion

Comment: can u help me in another issue not related to it? @Lion

Comment: you should ask another question for that as per stack overflow guide lines! and in that new question anyone can help you :)

Comment: i have asked it there before they public devote my question that why i ask here from u . @Lion

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{

    NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    newString = [newString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

    NSCharacterSet *numbersOnly = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"];
    NSCharacterSet *characterSetFromTextField = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:string];

    BOOL stringIsValid = [numbersOnly isSupersetOfSet:characterSetFromTextField];
    if(!stringIsValid)
        return stringIsValid;

    int length = (int)newString.length;

    if(newString.length > 0 && newString.length < 3)
    {
        // Need to check if first two character 9 or 92.
        NSString *firstTwoChar=[newString substringToIndex:length];

        if([firstTwoChar isEqualToString:@"9"] || [firstTwoChar isEqualToString:@"92"])
            return TRUE;
        else
            return FALSE;

        NSLog(@"%@",firstTwoChar);
    }


    return YES;
}
```

Comment: thnx for ur answer ,  but i got it from another guy . @Nirmalsinh

Comment: can u help me in my another problem? @Nirmalsinh

Comment: Yes please tell me

Comment: im sending some images by encoding them in base64 but they are not going in database. Do u know how can we send that to database. I can share code with u if u give me ur email address. @Nirmalsinh

Comment: You can use AFNetworking to upload image on server. https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Comment: actually i haven't done this before can u check my code and if there are any changes or anything wrong u can edited, i need ur help . @Nirmalsinh

Comment: Sent u mail. please check it. @Nirmalsinh